# Porque no Funciona el KeyCode en Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

La función `keyCode` no funciona en Chrome pero el Firefox funciona muy bien, al presionar el <kbd>Tab</kbd> en el input `calcular` me debe gatillar la función.

aqui mi código:

```js
$("#calcular").keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = event.keyCode;
  console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (keycode == 9) {
      $("input[name=Comentarioo]").focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="calcular" value="">
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) ya no forma parte de los estándares Web y su soporte por parte de los navegadores podría desaparecer en cualquier momento, por lo que no es recomendable su uso. Deberías usar [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) o `key` en su lugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres, puedes utilizar el metodo `keydown` asi:

```js
 $("#calcular").keydown(function(event) {
          var keycode = event.keyCode;
          
            if (keycode == 9) {

                $("input[name=Comentarioo]").focus();
            }

        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="calcular" value="">
```

Comment: diste la respuesta pero no explicaste el porque. Resulta que `keypress` no captura todas las teclas presionadas (como por ejemplo tab, ctrl, alt, etc.), las que si capturan todas las teclas presionadas son `keyup` o `keydown` pero dado que la tecla tab tiene una función al presionarla no te sirve `keyup` porque al momento de presionar tab ya perdiste el focus del input (porque al presionar tab te cambia el focus de elementos) así que debes usar `keydown`